# how to overcome indexout of bound at line no 8 of my code for the amount = int(values[1])

Tags: python

Write a program that computes the net amount of a bank account based a transaction log from console input. The transaction log format is shown as following:

```
D 100
W 200
```

D means deposit while W means withdrawal.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
D 300
D 300
W 200
D 100
Then, the output should be:
500
`enter code here`

```
tot = 0
n = int(input())
i = 0
while(i < n):
    x = input()
    values = x.split(" ")
    operation = values[0]
    amount = int(values[1])
    if operation == "D":
        tot += amount
    elif operation == "W":
        tot -= amount
    else:
        pass
    i += 1
print("total=", tot)
```

Comment: To be fair, even though it is homework, the error is in the post title, we have the code OP attempted, and we have expected input/output.

Comment: OP - you must be getting bad input. Try debugging by putting a `print(repr(x))` statement just above line 8. What does it print out? We can't help you unless you give us the answer -- http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
This program requires manual input.  Please hard-code the problem input into your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.stdin instead of input() here...
This makes it easier to loop through the input lines instead of reading input() twice. It's more concise and easier to understand and debug.

```
import sys

total = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = line.split(' ')
    if parts[0] == 'D':
        total += int(parts[1])
    elif parts[0] == 'W':
        total -= int(parts[1])
    else:
        continue

print('Total = ' + str(total))
```

Comment: I think you should explain why you've chosen to make the changes you've made.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to attempt to debug your code.

What is n? Is it what you expect it to be?

What is x? Is *it* what you expect it to be?

Is `values = x.split(" " )` doing what you think it should be doing?

My guess is malformed input, but without additional information, it's very difficult to say exactly what's wrong.